# Getting GeoCoordinates from pressing pin on Windows Phone 7 map

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mouseevent, bing-maps

I am working on a Windows Phone 7 app that displays SF MUNI stops and times. I already published it, but want to add map functionality. So, I added a map, on which is displayed stops (inbound or outbound) for a specific user picked route. Here is the code I have for that, which works and displays each stop on a route:

```
//coords is an array of GeoCoordinates for each stop
//limit is the number of stops
GeoCoordinate [] coords=new GeoCoordinate[limit];

//pin is an array of Pushpins for each stop to add to the map
Pushpin[] pin = new Pushpin[limit];

for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
   pin[i] = new Pushpin();
}


for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
  coords[i] = new GeoCoordinate(Convert.ToDouble(latitude[inb[i]]), Convert.ToDouble(longitude[inb[i]]));//populate coords array
   pin[i].Location = coords[i];//assign coords to pushpin location for each stop
}


//wires up event handler for clicking on each stop
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
  pin[i].MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(pin_MouseLeftButtonUp);
}  



//Adds a pin at each stop's geocoords for each station
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
  map1.Children.Add(pin[i]);
```

So, the above code does place pushpins at each geocoordinate correctly. What I am totally stumped at, is how, if I press a pushpin, do I get the geocoordinate for that pushpin? In other words, when I press a pushpin, I want to capture pin[i].Location (which is a GeoCoordinate) in some sorta variable.

thanks, I hope this explains my problem.

Amanda

Comment: You should use the Tap event instead (and make sure to remove it when leaving the page!) and you can put a reference to the GeoCoordinate in pin[i].Tag. You'll just need to cast it out off of sender pressedCoord = (GeoCoordinate)((PushPin)sender).Tag;

Comment: How do I indicate the question is solved?

Comment: Great! I just went ahead and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `Tap` event instead of `MouseLeftButtonUp`. (and make sure to remove it when leaving the page!) and you can put a reference to the `GeoCoordinate` in `pin[i].Tag`.

`Tag` is a grab bag reference to whatever you want -- in your case, you want to put a `GeoCoordinate`, but you can put whatever you want -- and it exists on all `UIElements`.

In your `Tap` event listener, you can get a reference to your `GeoCoordinate` like:

```
pressedCoord = (GeoCoordinate)((PushPin)sender).Tag;
```